# How does assembly addressing work?

Tags: assembly

I am looking at code for assembly language. `SP` register is initially set to `50`. In each step, the contents of memory locations in a warehouse are displayed which points to `SP`.

```
mov ax,6
push ax
mov bx,3
push bx
mov cx,1
push cx
mov dx,8
push dx
pop ax
pop bx
pop dx
pop cx
```

The final value in the registers are :

```
ax=8
bx=1
cx=3
dx=6
```

How does this work? How does the above commands translate into these final values?

Comment: This seems like it would be trivially answerable by reading the documentation for your variant of assembly. If reading the documentation doesn't help, then please [edit] your question to explain how your research failed to answer your question, so that we can give you a useful answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (too trivial).  See the x86 tag wiki page for links to docs.

Answer (score 0):

1. You push 6,3,1,8 to the stack
2. You remove 8 from the stack and copy it to ax
3. You remove 1 from the stack and copy it to bx
4. You remove 3 from the stack and copy it to cx
5. you remove 6 from the stack and copy it to dx

Therefore :

```
ax=8
bx=1
cx=3
dx=6
```

I can't really explain it more than that without writing a documentation about what is a stack.

example from wikipedia : 
[image]